# CakePHP project on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, cakephp-3.0

I have cakePHP project on a subdomain like admin.example.com that is mapped to example.com/cakeProject/ folder, but when i go to that url it always adds the project folder: admin.example.com/cakeProject/.

What do i need to change to get rid of that folder name in subdomain?
Thanks

Comment: what is in your .htaccess file?

Comment: In cakeProject folder i have the stock .htaccess file:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
There is also one in webroot folder of the project:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>